# Referencing a list from list of lists

Tags: python, function, pandas, iteration

I have a 2 dataframes
One- Score Card for scoring student marks 
Second One-Student dataset.

I want to apply score card on a given student dataset to compute score and aggregate them. I'm trying to devlop a generic function that  takes the 
score card and applies on any studentmarks dataset

```
import pandas as pd
score_card_data = {
        'subject_id': ['MATHS', 'SCIENCE', 'ARTS'],
        'bin_list': [[0,25,50,75,100], [0,20,40,60,80,100], [0,20,40,60,80,100]], 
        'bin_value': [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6,7] ]}
score_card_data = pd.DataFrame(score_card_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'bin_list', 'bin_value'])
score_card_data

student_scores = {
        'STUDENT_ID': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3','S4','S5'],
        'MATH_MARKS': [10,15,25,65,75], 
        'SCIENCE_MARKS': [8,15,20,35,85],
        'ARTS_MARKS':[55,90,95,88,99]}
student_scores = pd.DataFrame(student_scores, columns = ['STUDENT_ID', 'MATH_MARKS', 'SCIENCE_MARKS','ARTS_MARKS'])
student_scores
```

Functions
Define bins
Apply the bins over columns

```
bins = list(score_card_data.loc[score_card_data['subject_id'] == 'MATHS', 'bin_list'])
student_scores['MATH_SCORE'] = pd.cut(student_scores['MATH_MARKS'],bins, labels='MATHS_MARKS')

Error:ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

I'm trying to convert the cellvalue to a string and it is getting detected as an object. Any way to resolve

How can I make the function more generic?

Thanks 
Pari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `bins[0]` to extract the `list`, which otherwise raises the `ValueError`:

```
bins[0]
[0, 25, 50, 75, 100]

type(bins[0])
<class 'list'>

student_scores['MATH_SCORE'] = pd.cut(student_scores['MATH_MARKS'], bins[0])

  STUDENT_ID  MATH_MARKS  SCIENCE_MARKS  ARTS_MARKS MATH_SCORE
0         S1          10              8          55    (0, 25]
1         S2          15             15          90    (0, 25]
2         S3          25             20          95    (0, 25]
3         S4          65             35          88   (50, 75]
4         S5          75             85          99   (50, 75]
```

I left out the `labels` because you'd need to provide a list of four labels given there are five cutoffs / bin edges.